# How to reduce the number of variables in the signature of method in child class? Java refactoring

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have an abstract class `A` which does the main work, and also there are classes `B` and `C` which extend class A and implements the method doTheFinalMove().

```
public abstract class A {

    public Object aMethod() {
        Integer var1 = calculateVar1();
        String var2 = calculateVar2();
        Boolean var3 = calculateVar3();
        Object var4 = calculateVar4();
        Object var5 = calculateVar5();

        return doTheFinalMove(var1,
                var2,
                var3,
                var4,
                var5
        );
    }

    protected abstract Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                             String var2,
                                             Boolean var3,
                                             Object var4,
                                             Object var5);

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                    String var2,
                                    Boolean var3,
                                    Object var4,
                                    Object var5) {
        return doMyStaff(
                var1,
                var2,
                var3,
                var4,
                var5);
    }
}

public class C extends A {

    @Override
    protected Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                    String var2,
                                    Boolean var3,
                                    Object var4,
                                    Object var5) {
        return doMyStaff(var1, var2);
    }
}
```

So, class `C` unlike class `B` needs only two of the five variables to do its job, but in order to keep the inheritance of the class `A`, I should use all the five variables in the signature of `doTheFinalMove()` in `A` and `C` classes. I would like to refactor this code in the way that class `C` keep in its signature only those variables that it really needs (var1 and var2). I want to avoid using `Object... args` stuff, so I thought about wrapping these variables into an Object(I mean some inheritance like BasicParams and ExtendedParams) and then using an AbstractFactory or smth like that, but I don't know how to do it properly.
I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you can overload many form of your method in the abstract.
You call from the more specific to the less specific in the abstract, then only override the needed method.

```
public abstract class A {

    public Object aMethod() {
        Integer var1 = calculateVar1();
        String var2 = calculateVar2();
        Boolean var3 = calculateVar3();
        Object var4 = calculateVar4();
        Object var5 = calculateVar5();

        return doTheFinalMove(var1,
                var2,
                var3,
                var4,
                var5
        );
    }    

    protected Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                         String var2,
                                         Boolean var3,
                                         Object var4,
                                         Object var5){
         return doTheFinalMove(var1,var2);
    }

    protected Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                         String var2){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("You have to override one of the doTheFinalMove method");
    }


}


public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                String var2,
                                Boolean var3,
                                Object var4,
                                Object var5) {
    return doMyStaff(
            var1,
            var2,
            var3,
            var4,
            var5);
     }
}

public class C extends A {

    @Override
    protected Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                String var2) {
        return doMyStaff(var1, var2);
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid the exception and force the implementation of the method by the compiler, you may add Abstract levels, but the complexity augmentation is only usefull if you have more than 1 implementation imho (i.e. more than only B and C)

Variant with 1 more abstraction:

```
public abstract class A {

    public Object aMethod() {
        Integer var1 = calculateVar1();
        String var2 = calculateVar2();
        Boolean var3 = calculateVar3();
        Object var4 = calculateVar4();
        Object var5 = calculateVar5();

        return doTheFinalMove(var1,
                var2,
                var3,
                var4,
                var5
        );
    }    

    protected Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                         String var2,
                                         Boolean var3,
                                         Object var4,
                                         Object var5);



}
```

public abstract class A2 extends A {

```
    protected Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                         String var2,
                                         Boolean var3,
                                         Object var4,
                                         Object var5){
         return doTheFinalMove(var1,var2);
    }

    protected abstract Object doTheFinalMove(Integer var1,
                                         String var2);

}
// Then C should extends A2 instead of A
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case I should to implement doTheFinalMove() with args in class B, because it an abstract method

Comment: Oh yes, you have to implement all of them, less control, or add another abstract level, you need to have many method for this to be usefull, I update my answer

Answer (score 1):

the simpliest thing it comes to mind is to overload the function:

```
public Object doTheFinalMove(var1, var2) {
    return doTheFinalMove(var1, null, null, var2, null);
}
```

Where, instead of null you place the values that are correct for your implementation.

I placed that as public because protected methods are usually ment only for internal use, while public methods are for common use.

Also you cannot directly change the overridden method, because it could
be used inside the parent class or in other applications. That's why override works only if you use the exact same format (and possibly behave as intended in the main class).

Comment: I would propose exactly the opposite: overload with an abstract, but call from the 5 parameters function the 2 parameters function. Maybe you could modify it.

Comment: I see your point. But that would be your answer. Don't want to steal the credits. Plus it really depends on how the thing works internally. I'm having the same exact problem in one of my libreries.

Comment: Ok I do the answer with the modification